# Interested in running mid2015 MBP 15 with AMD gpu on a Dell U4919DW

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

I am concerned if the resolution of the U4919DW is supported since it is a whopping 5160 x 1440.

I have a dual monitor now and one of them died....so thinking to upgrade to this 49" monster.

What sort of refresh and resolution can I expect if I connect this dell U4919 to a 2015 MacBook Pro with a 15 inch screen running Mojave?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) as this will help in what is and isn't on-topic for this site, as well as the best way to ask a question that gets a good response. All the best!